# How use the << to assign a value to a matrix element like Eigen？

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I think the Matrix or Vector in Eigen is overload the "<<" and "," to implement that.Here are my implementation in my code.

```
Matrix4f& operator,(float num)
{
    _mat[index] = num;
    if (index < 16)
    {
        index++;
    }
    if (index == 15)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    return *this;
}

friend Matrix4f& operator<<(Matrix4f& m, float num)
{
    m._mat[m.index] = num;
    ++m.index;
    return m;
}
```

it works well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJDs7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeghF.png)

but i want to know how implement the function when number of enter elements is not accord with the Matrix's need, the program will report the error.
For example,
Vectro3f vec << 1,2;
it will report the error.

Comment: what error? Please post a [mcve] of the code in the question toghether with the error message. When your container has no space for the new element, you need to make more space

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need any of this.

Comment: Anyways, you could compare your index to the product of the numbers of columns and rows of the fixed-sized matrix (rows(), cols()).

Comment: Here is how Eigen defines the CommaInitializer if that is what you are looking for: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/CommaInitializer.h